# ActionBarSherlock - Show overflowed action items as icon + text

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

**Context**

I am creating an action bar with some action items, using ActionbarSherlock. Some of them are overflowed, so they are shown in the overflow submenu.

**My problem**

Those overflowed items are shown in the submenu just as mere texts.

I have tried `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM` and `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT` for `setShowAsAction()` but both have the same behavior:

[image: Overflowed items without icon]

**What I want**

Is it possible to show these items in the overflow submenu as `<their_icon>` + `<their_text>`? Something like this:

[image: Overflowed items with icon]

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this?

Comment: Not yet... However, it looks like the native ActionBar (API level 11+) is able to do it (see: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html, especifically the image of gallery application in Android 4.0), or is it a special "hand-made" implementation?

Comment: @Cristian, there's no such example image in the mentioned link. The only "drop down" menu that has icons in that page is the "Share" menu, but that is not the "Action Overflow"

Comment: @Gavriel, you're right, I realized now. I guess. then, for that "drop-down" the custom "menu-submenu" pattern posted by Arise is used, isn't it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't understand either why submenus can have icons and menus only text.
Maybe adding menu items as submenus to the *root* menu could help you. :)

Just a mention, adding icons like this will force you to use the ActionBar (Sherlock) and not the standard way of displaying menus at the bottom when pressing the menu key in older versions of Android.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/root_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="More">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings_holo_light"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="About"/>
   </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Arise. That's what I did to achieve this appearance. However, I didn't post it as a solution because I consider it a workaround for my particular case, since it implies forcing the distribution of action items in the action bar (i.e. forcing them to be 1, 2 or 3), instead of letting the system decide how many of them are to be shown. Anyway, your answer is helpful if you want to define a specific _tree_ in the action bar menu

Comment: Great answer if you know what your drop list contains, basically when it doesn't need to be dynamic. Thank you!

Comment: I'll finally mark this as the solution, since there's no current way of adding the icons except for creating submenus

Comment: There are many other way to do this, but you done in easier way. +1

Answer (score 6):

1, change the value to true of "mOptionalIconsVisible" in com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.java. Then you will see the icons always.
Only work for ActionBarSherlockCompact.java.

2, Change source code to add an api for MenuBuilder.java and MenuWrapper.java to set the icon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rohn.chan. However, I would like to apply a solution which doesn't imply modifying ActionBarSherlock's source code, since I should then apply it in every update of this library.

Comment: A bit late, but you don't have to apply the modification each time. Simply get a copy of the Actionbar sherlock repository, make the modification, and pull the updates. The new changesets are applied when you pull, but your changes are not erased in the process.

Answer (score 5):

I have a work around for such scenario. If you are sure about what you want to put in overflow menu, then you can put them in a submenu, and you can put the icon and title for that sub menu item along with sub menus by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

This is what I have done to achieve this functionality:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "MENU ONE TITLE")
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, 0, 2, "MENU TWO TITLE");

    subMenu.add(0, 2, 2, "SUB MENU ONE TITLE")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.sub_menu_one_icon);

    subMenu.add(0, 3, 3, "SUB MENU TWO TITLE")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.sub_menu_two_icon);

    MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem();
    subMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_two_icon);
    subMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: This is the programmatic equivalent to @Arise's answer. The problem is I do NOT know exactly what has to be in the overflow menu, it should be automatic (i.e. decided by system). For example, in a device with enough space, the overflow menu in the example I posted shouldn't be shown, as there is enough room to show all items.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , there is a way to add an icon to the text even for popup menus that are created for the overflow menu. For example:

```
final MenuItem menuItem=...
final ImageSpan imageSpan=new ImageSpan(this,R.drawable.ic_stat_app_icon);
final CharSequence title=" "+menuItem.getTitle();
final SpannableString spannableString=new SpannableString(title);
spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan,0,1,0);
menuItem.setTitle(spannableString);
```

This will put an icon at the beginning of the menu item, right before its original text.